# How to activate Bluetooth in Delphi FMX?

Tags: delphi, bluetooth, firemonkey

How can I disable and enable Bluetooth in Delphi FMX?

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth is meant to be enabled/disabled only by the user, not by applications.  There is no API in FMX to enable/disable Bluetooth *directly*.  However, FMX's [`TBluetoothManager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Bluetooth.TBluetoothManager) class does have an [`EnableBluetooth`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Bluetooth.TBluetoothManager.EnableBluetooth) property.  At this time, this property is only implemented for Android, in which it triggers a system prompt that asks the user if Bluetooth can be turned on, and if the user says yes then Android turns it on.